# javascript find node without id

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Due to a limitation of the Javascript library I'm using, I can't assign an id to a `<div>`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to attach a Tooltip object from Tipped, a Javascript tooltip library, to the element without an id. I don't know if this is possible, but I'm trying to find the object via other means which will hopefully allow me to modify the id.

The element I'm looking for is a button on a toolbar, but it's not an HTML button. It's a `<div>` that has CSS styles and Javascript events assigned to make it look and feel like a button. I know the class name of the parent and I know the id of the grandparent `<div>`, but that's as much as I know. Part of the issue is that there doesn't seem to be a good reference for how to iteratively operate on HTML objects once you get a reference to them. I've seen plenty of examples like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsById("asdf")
```

but no follow-up code showing how to actually do anything. What's in x? What methods does it have? I know of innerHTML and innerTEXT, but I can't figure out if they apply to x, a child of x, or ???. The Chrome console has helped a little bit, but I'm basically lost.

This is the relevant code for my button:

[image: DIVs in my page (no id on the Export button)]

As you can see, there is no id on the Export button, but the parent has a class name and the grandparent has an id. The other snag is that the grandparent's id isn't static. It always starts with "dhxtoolbar" and there is only one toolbar on the page, but I haven't been able to make a regex search find the toolbar.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to attach a Tipped tooltip to the Export button. I think Tipped requires an id, but maybe it doesn't. Regardless, I'd like to understand more about how to iterate through the DOM and, as a bonus, figure out how or if I can change the id of an element on a live page. Thanks.

Comment: Have you researched [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)?

Comment: I'd never heard of that, but this is exactly what I'm talking about: the page you linked to shows how to use the single API method and the follow-up code on the API page says nothing about what to do next.

function handle(evt) {
  var x = evt.target.querySelector("span");
  ...
  // Do something with x
}

What is the "Do something with x"??

Comment: Well what is it that makes you want to find the element?  In other words, if your problem were already solved as to how to *find* the element, what would you do next?

Comment: I want to change the id of the element, so I'm trying to understand if there is a way to do x.id = "something" or any other method to change something about x. All of the documentation I've found shows something like x.innerHTML or x.style.display, but nothing I try seems to be working.

Comment: Well once you have the node you want then `x.id = "something";` is pretty much exactly what you would do.  [This reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) is a pretty good place to start - it's about the API on DOM elements etc.

Comment: A javascript library that is not capable of handling ids, and you feel limited by it? You are right, throw it away! Btw, I'd be interested in the way it threatens you.

Comment: The library is quite good, but the developers didn't intend for it to be used this way. They offer a tooltip mechanism via XML definitions and other Javascript APIs, but none of it comes close to Tipped. The library is called dhtmlx and the object I'm using is dhtmlxToolbar. Pointy - thanks for the link and information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was trying to have explained:

```
var Obj         = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
var ObjChildren = Obj[0].getElementsByTagName("tag")
var searchText = "string";

for (var i = 0; i < ObjChildren.length; i < i++) {
    if (ObjChildren[i].innerHTML == searchText) {
        console.log(ObjChildren[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Tipped](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped/documentation) actually accepts any CSS selector as an argument. If the class is unique, you could target it that way:

```
Tipped.create('.dhx_toolbar_btn', 'some tooltip text');
```

Or if the class isn't unique, you could try target it via the tree structure. Made up example:

```
Tipped.create('.header .sidebar .dhx_toolbar_btn', 'some tooltip text');
```

I noticed in your html that the buttons have empty `title` attributes (or maybe your inspector just added them). If you can set the `title` attribute for the buttons Tipped will pick it up automatically. Example:

```
<div class="dhx_toolbar_btn" title="test title">
```

You would then only have to use:

```
Tipped.create('.dhx_toolbar_btn');
```

And Tipped will automatically pick up the title and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't know that Tipped could use a CSS selector. Unfortunately, the button class isn't unique. There are other buttons on the toolbar with the same class, but they all have different text if that matters.

Comment: In response to your updated answer, I think the title aspect of this could be interesting. I'll have to do some research on Tipped because I really need the Tooltip to use AJAX to dynamically load content into the tooltip. I'm not sure if I can accomplish that using the title method you described, though, so I'll check it out. Thanks.