# Detect missing attributes from HTML element - Regular Expression

Tags: html, expression

I have a directory of HTML files, and would like to find out all the  elements that have a missing 'id' attribute.

I figure using a text editor combined with regular expressions would best work.

Im currently stuck with this: `<div[^>]*id` which would list down all the div elements with id attributes. How would I detect those without them?

Thanks!

Comment: How about javascript?

Comment: if you want to use javascript then use following link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006220/javascript-find-node-without-id

Comment: Hi @Rony , I only want to search for these tags using an editor. Thanks.

Comment: ok... so u find anything yet?

Comment: @Rony none yet. Dont think I can use Javascript to accomplish this as I need to search all the HTML files in my directory, and append 'id' attributes to each too. Thanks